# R - What does "incomplete block on file" mean?

Tags: r, package

I am using RStudio, and am trying to use packrat with my current project.
I click the checkbox "Use packrat with this project" and press OK, where I get the following output from the console:

```
    > packrat::init()
Initializing packrat project in directory:
- "/Users/Ash/Dropbox/Uni/2014/Thesis/Code/R"

Adding these packages to packrat:
            _         
    packrat   0.4.0.12

Fetching sources for packrat (0.4.0.12) ... Error in snapshotSources(project, activeRepos(project), allRecordsFlat) : 
  Errors occurred when fetching source files:
Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : 
  incomplete block on file
```

I can't find much on this error, but based on [this](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/utils/R/tar.R) code (searching for the error string, incomplete block on file), it seems this relates to an unexpected file length/size.

I assume the download may be corrupt? But I have tried multiple times.

Or perhaps I don't have the correct permissions? But the project file should have no issues here.

Has anybody else had this issue?

Comment: Related: I had this issue while trying to install devtools. It was failing upstream while trying to install curl, because I didn't have the libcurl4 dev packages installed. Fixed that by doing `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I assume the download may be corrupt? But I have tried multiple times.

Yes. The download may corrupt or according to [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Installing-R-R-packages-td4676808.html) in the *R help* mailing list the issue might be caused by corrupted package on the server itself. In latter case it can be solved by selecting different mirror for downloading package.

**NOTE** I'll describe a solution, which uses R console instead of Rstudio GUI, because I used to install packages this way. Described approach can probably work with package installs from GUI as well.

When you install package from R console by executing:

```
> install.packages("<package_name>")
```

You are presented with the list of available mirrors to choose from:

```
 1: 0-Cloud [https]                2: Austria [https]
 3: Chile [https]                  4: China (Beijing 4) [https]
 ...
```

Just select another one (preferably one close to your location to have faster download).

---

If you're not presented with such choice, but download starts right away, you have a default mirror configured (for example Rstudio automatically sets `https://cran.rstudio.com/` as a default). You can check your selected mirror by issuing:

```
> getOption("repos")["CRAN"]
                       CRAN
"https://cran.rstudio.com/"
```

To reset default mirror you can use following commands:

```
> r <- getOption("repos")
> r["CRAN"] <- "@CRAN@"
> options(repos=r)
```

Now, when you try to install new package you can choose another mirror as described above.

Comment: Thanks Yarslav. I no longer have the project code that caused this issue so I cannot verify. I have marked as correct as this seems to be a plausible explanation and solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Answering a million years later... But if anyone gets here as I did while looking for `Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :  incomplete block on file`, your problem may be related to the presence of private packages in your code.

Follow this [thread](https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/447).
The last comment saved my life.

You need to build tar.gz of your custom private packages and save it a unique folder.
From there just run this code:

```
packrat::set_opts(local.repos = "path/to/the/folder/with/your/tar.gz/files")
packrat::install_local('yourpackage')
```

After that, run again `packarat::init()` and it's gonna be a happy day again.