# Installing package from a local zip file in R

Tags: r, installation, package, install.packages, local-files

I am trying to install a package in R from a local zip file. I have the zip file on a local drive, but when I go to *Packages --> Install a package from a local zip file* I get the following warning:

```
> utils:::menuInstallLocal()
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : cannot open the connection
```

In addition: Warning messages:

```
1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : cannot open compressed file 'cirt/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

What is going on here?

Many thanks in advance,
A

Comment: Is this within RStudio?

Comment: Might not be an exact duplicate but following the directions for the other answer should address the problem.

Comment: *"Installing package from a local zip file"* is an infinitely clearer title...

Answer (score 16):

Try :

```
install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL, type="source")
```

It will allow you to select the desired zip file.

Comment: Thank you! But now I get the following message:Installing package into ‘C:/Users/walcza/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : 
  incomplete block on file
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\walcza\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "C:/Windows/System32/cirt/R/cirt"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages(file.choose("cirt"), repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘C:/Windows/System32/cirt/R/cirt’ had non-zero exit status
>

Comment: See this related answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34712100/170792

Comment: Actually, type = "source" or "binary", depending on what the zip is. ("binary" selects automatically from "mac.binary"/ "mac.binary.mavericks"/ "win.binary")